# Add information about upcoming events to the chat page

Tags: feature-request, chat

Upcoming events are listed in the chat rooms page, but not in the chat room itself.  If you only go directly to the room, then you're a chat participant (therefore likely to be interested in an event), but not necessarily aware that the event is coming up.

It would be nice to information about the next scheduled event for that room (if there is one) in the chat room itself, perhaps just under the starred items.

(Originally suggested in [this answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/457/periodic-recommendation-chats/484#484)).